# jQuery onclick copy paste function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to copy text from textbox to textbox 1 on click of anchor tag 1. It is working fine. How can I also create anchor tag 2 which copy the text from textbox to textbox 2. ([JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/yLp3c2zd/2/))

```
<textarea id="textarea" placeholder="text"></textarea>
<a onclick="fn_copy();">target </a>
<a>target 2 </a>
<textarea id="target_1"></textarea>
<textarea id="target_2"></textarea>

<script>
function fn_copy()
{
    var temp = document.getElementById("textarea").value;
    if(temp != "")
    {
        document.getElementById("target_1").value = temp;
    }
    else
        alert("Text is Empty");
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
function fn_copy(data)
{
    var temp = document.getElementById("textarea").value;
    if(temp != "")
    {
        document.getElementById("target_"+data).value = temp;
    }
    else
        alert("Text is Empty");
    }
</script>
<body>
<textarea id="textarea" placeholder="text"></textarea>
<a onclick="fn_copy(1);">target </a>
<a onclick="fn_copy(2);">target 2</a>
<textarea id="target_1"></textarea>
<textarea id="target_2"></textarea>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked like a charm !

Answer (score 0):

Why not expand your function so that it accepts parameters for the elements you want to copy.

```
  function fn_copy(from, to) {
    var temp = document.getElementById(from).value;
    if (temp != "") {
      document.getElementById(to).value = temp;
    } else {
      alert("Text is Empty");
    }
    return false;
  }
```

And modified markup

```
<textarea id="textarea" placeholder="text"></textarea>
<a onclick="fn_copy('textarea','target_1');">target </a>
<a onclick="fn_copy('textarea','target_2');">target 2 </a>
<textarea id="target_1"></textarea>
<textarea id="target_2"></textarea>
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/fwxeot6a/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a parameter to the fn_copy function with the value of id textarea

```js
function fn_copy(id)
{
    var temp = document.getElementById("textarea").value;
    if(temp != "")
    {
       document.getElementById(id).value = temp;
    }
    else
    alert("Text is Empty");
 }
```

```html
 <textarea id="textarea" placeholder="text"></textarea>
 
 
<a onclick="fn_copy('target_1');">target 1</a>
<a onclick="fn_copy('target_2');">target 2</a>

<textarea  id="target_1"></textarea>
<textarea  id="target_2"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Wrap It All in a `<form>` Tag

Add the `target` attribute to each link and assign each value to that of the `#id` of a `<textarea>`. The terse syntax used to access the `<form>` and the `<textarea>s` is provided by the **[`HTMLFormControlsCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormControlsCollection)**. [**Event Delegation**](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/handling_events_for_many_elements.htm) pattern was used to handle the click event with only one event handler on the `<form>` instead an onclick event handler on each `<a>`. By having a parent element handle the click event, all children elements and any dynamically added elements are handled by one handler.

---

### Demo

```js
var form = document.forms[0];
var ui = form.elements;
form.onclick = fnCopy;

function fnCopy(e) {
  var tgt = e.target;
  var txt = ui.textarea.value;
  if (tgt.tagName === 'A' && txt.length > 0) {
    var textTo = tgt.target;
    document.querySelector('#' + textTo).value = txt;
  } else if (tgt.tagName === 'A' && txt.length < 1) {
    alert('No text available');
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<form id='form'>
  <textarea id="textarea" placeholder="Enter text"></textarea><br>
  <a href='#/' target='target1'>target 1</a>
  <a href='#/' target='target2'>target 2</a><br>
  <textarea id="target1" placeholder='target1'></textarea><br>
  <textarea id="target2" placeholder='target2'></textarea>
</form>
```